# Why won't CSS Keyframes work with Position Absolute?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, css-animations

I have worked on a searchbar that appears when user scrolls down the page, and disappears when they scroll up. I was able to get the animation working perfectly with **position: fixed**, however, the same styling is *not* working with **position: absolute**.

Apparently when the iOS keyboard appears, elements with position: fixed go haywire - so I must make this work with **position: absolute**. The problem now is that the behavior does not work at all. It is actually behaving almost in reverse, where it appears when the page load and immediately translates upward in a flickering manner. Can anyone come up with a solution?

My code below and is in ReactJS and Scss and you can find the sandbox version here: https://codesandbox.io/s/lxyx58jo4m?fontsize=14. If you are unfamiliar with React, isSearchBar is determining if the class is **show-search-bar** or **hide-search-bar** based on the scroll

```js
<div className={`search-bar-mobile-container ${isSearchBar ? "show-search-bar" : "hide-search-bar"}`} >
      <form>
      </form>
    </div>
```

```css
@keyframes exit-up-search-bar {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-76px);
    height: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes entrance-down-search-bar {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
    height: 76px;
  }
}
.search-bar-mobile-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 76px;
  background-color: #00c0d1;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000000001;
  top:-76px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  &.show-search-bar{
    animation: entrance-down-search-bar 0.3s forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    top:0;
  }
  &.hide-search-bar{
    animation: exit-up-search-bar 5s forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    top:-76px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your `HTML`?

Comment: I have attached the JSX which is essentially HTML in ReactJS. The logic to determine which class is solid.

Comment: have you used https://codesandbox.io before? Can you create a minimal example of your problem there so we can see it for ourselves?

Comment: here I made one https://codesandbox.io/s/0knomo0ql for you. is the issue there?

Comment: There's a lot going on with your toggling styles, so I'm not sure if it'll fix your issue, but you should definitely check out [CSS Transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) instead of keyframes.

Comment: @azium I have attached the codesandbox link